# Laravel | Speed difference between vhost and php Server

Tags: laravel, pagespeed, vhosts

I made a vhost for my local Laravel installation. The thing is, that the variation with 127.0.0.1:8000 is so much faster than the "example.local"-vhost which points to the public/ directory of Laravel. Of course the vhost uses Apache.
Why is there such a speed difference? While the IP version has a lighthouse speed score of 100 the vhost has only 72 which is a significant difference. Can anyone help me with this? How do I get the same performance?